# Bluemix and Push code not working

Tags: ibm-cloud

I am using Android and IBM push service and have created an application as per the BluelistPush but my application is not starting. Each time I click the app in the emulator it shows application has stopped. only on the first time some exception at runtime as soon as I load the application. It was working before when I was using only ibm data and object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this issue is happening to you after adding dependencies for IBM push.

Please ensure that you have added the below lines of code in the `onCreate()` method of your application

```
IBMPush.initializeService();
```

and then start using the service as below

```
IBMPush.getService();
```

else chances are there that you may encounter a runtime exception while the app gets loaded.

Comment: This helped. I did not initialize the push service.

Comment: Are you using the node.js runtime?